# how to edit autoplay action for device? (Windows 7/8)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, iphone, autoplay

I'm looking for a way to add a program to the list of default autoplay actions when I connect a device, specifically opening up [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) when connecting an iPhone.

[Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) will let you edit autoplay entries for different media, however not for devices.

Regedit magic also seems to have failed me so far, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/AutoplayHandlers` and its children do not seem to have references to `KnownDevices`, `iPhone`, and/or the name of my device.

Any and all help is welcome.

Comment: havent u checked by altering the default configurations at controlpanel-->autoplay?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your iPhone, then open Control Panel → Hardware → AutoPlay. At the bottom of the list you'll find Devices. For Windows 7 and 8, if your Program doesn't show in the drop down, set to "Ask me every time", then replug in your iPhone. When the autoplay pops up, select "Choose a program from a list". In Windows 8.1, I haven't found how to choose something other than what is in the list yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do this is to use the free program "[Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/)".  There's a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Npb8pYXHh4Q) that explains how it's used, but it's fairly straightforward for someone with some experience and knowledge.

It lets you explicitly add programs to the autoplay selection, among many other things.  Once you've done that, you can select it as the default action from then on from the list in the Autoplay options in the control panel.